# Best Password Management Software for Development Group - looking for suggestions

Tags: passwords

Our development and consulting teams (about 25 people) are looking for software to manage all of the passwords we have for our organization and for our clients.  We looked at Keepass but it is not truly a database system nor does it have support for multiple concurrent updates.

Needs:
-Uses database (versus shared text / XML file)
-Ability to segment passwords by project / role / individuals

Wants (but not required):
-Web based
-Mobile support

Anybody have a good recommendation?

Thanks in advance!

-Sig

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind a hosted solution, I find online password manager [PassPack](https://www.passpack.com/) very promising. The one thing missing are roles or accounts such that different projects would need to use distinct PassPack accounts. This would work very well where you setup a project for a customer and later pass on the PassPack account to the customer for passing all project related passwords to the customer in one go.

In case you are worried about security: everything is encrypted on the browser side and only encrypted data is transmitted and stored on the server side. The weakest link is obviously the browser-side encryption which you could review since it is all in JavaScript. You also depend on the PassPack service being available but you can also export the data for backup.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure LDAP & Co. would let you do all that.

Answer (score 0):

Joel's entry on [Password management finally possible](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/11b.html) may be a good place to start.

Not sure it covers you on all bases though.

Comment: I read that - more of a personal password manager - not good for teams - thanks for the reply though..